# When I dump a pe from memory，how can I repair IAT?

Tags: reverse, malware, ida

I'm analyzing a malware, the malware decrypt a pe file to memory, like this

[image]

I use [ollydumpex](http://low-priority.appspot.com/ollydumpex/) for x64dbg to dump the memory,

[image]

then use IDA to analyze, but it like this

[image]

this is a dll, it will be injected to other process. so current process will not load it, so how can I to repaire it?

Answer (score 2):

First thing is OEP. On the screenshot I see EntryPoint (+0x28 to the address of PE\x00\x00 signature) as zero. So, first you need to find where this entrypoint is really located.

So, if you check `CreateRemoteThread` description:

> HANDLE CreateRemoteThread(
>     HANDLE                 hProcess,
>     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  lpThreadAttributes,
>     SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
>     LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
>     LPVOID                 lpParameter,
>     DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
>     LPDWORD                lpThreadId
>   );

You need argument `lpStartAddress`. This argument can be located in the line

```
4015C9  lea eax, dword ptr ds:[ebx+edi]
```

So, your edi value is 0x3CE0000 (which is ImageBase in another process) and ebx value is 0xB159 (this is EntryPoint RVA). In OllyDumpEx you have to write this value to the EntryPoint field.

Recovering import is a long process of analyzing all calls to the libraries and re-creating IMPORT_DIRECTORY and IAT table. You can write a script for that or use any existing. Another option is patching Scylla (which is open-source project) and adding ability to change ImageBase to some specific value (0x3CE0000 in your case).

Tools like ImpREC (Import Reconstructor) and Scylla are not suitable here without patch. The real problem here is that your DLL is not loaded like normal DLL. So, you can't select it with 'Pick DLL' in the ImpREC/Scylla.

But you can make some hack. Create 2 empty project - DLL, and EXE that loads a DLL. In exe load your DLL and after that write infinite loop like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {
     HANDLE hLib = LoadLibraryA("someDll.dll");
     DWORD old;
     // this will make your DLL writable.
     VirtualProtect((DWORD)hLib, 0x3C414, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old);
     DWORD pid = GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess());
     char addressBuffer[64];
     sprintf(addressBuffer, "ImageBase: %#x\nPID: %#x", (DWORD)hLib, pid);
     MessageBoxA(NULL, addressBuffer, "Donor DLL address", MB_OK);
     for (;;) Sleep(1000);
     return 0;
}
```

I recommend you to add some big data object to your DLL. This DLL will be a donor for your malware. Just add `int bigData[0x3C414];` somewhere outside of functions (functions data will be placed on the stack, but you need a big main module memory). I get 0x3C414 from EBP value as size of malware.

Now run this application and read ImageBase and PID from the messagebox. Then trace to the `OpenProcess` and replace third argument (`dwProcessId`) with PID of your application. Then trace to the line like in the screenshot, replace second argument with ImageBase and execute WriteProcessMemory. That's all! You can now restore IAT with ImpREC or Scilla. Just open your process and pick DLL someDll.dll. Type 0xB159 as EntryPoint/OEP and click `IAT AutoSearch`, then `Get Imports` and `Fix dump`. Good luck!